# How JBOSS recognizes EAR file

Tags: java, jboss

Hi I have EAR file and placed in Jboss Standalone/deployment path in Jboss server and it's working fine but the doubt is how the JBOSS is recognizing the EAR file ,Could you please briefly explain the internal flow of the JBOSS

Answer (score 2):

That's the JBoss File Deployment Scanner:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Deployment+Scanner+configuration

You can configure it via standalone.xml.

Basically it detects a new deployment file (EAR, WAR, JAR) (checks if the modification date is newer, if the file existed before).

You can also control it with special files like earname.dodeploy, *.doundeploy and it generates files indicating what it does: *.isdeploying, *.deployed.

Answer (score 1):

The deployment scanner is only used in standalone mode. Its job is to monitor a directory for new files and to deploy those files. It can be found in **standalone.xml**:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
<deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000"
   relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" />
</subsystem>
```

You can define more deployment-scanner entries to scan for deployments from more locations. The configuration showed will scan the **$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments** directory every five seconds. The runtime model is shown below, and uses default values for attributes not specified in the xml:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => {"scanner" => {"default" => {
    "auto-deploy-exploded" => false,
    "auto-deploy-zipped" => true,
    "deployment-timeout" => 60L,
    "name" => "default",
    "path" => "deployments",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir",
    "scan-enabled" => true,
    "scan-interval" => 5000
}}}
}
```

Deployment scanners can be added by modifying standalone.xml before starting up the server or they can be added and removed at runtime using the CLI(Command Line Interface).

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner/scanner=new:add(scan-interval=10000,relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir",path="other-deployments")
{"outcome" => "success"}
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner/scanner=new:remove                                              
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

You can also change the attributes at runtime, so for example to turn off scanning you can do

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner/scanner=default:write-attribute(name="scan-enabled",value=false)
{"outcome" => "success"}
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)                                    {
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => {"scanner" => {"default" => {
    "auto-deploy-exploded" => false,
    "auto-deploy-zipped" => true,
    "deployment-timeout" => 60L,
    "name" => "default",
    "path" => "deployments",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir",
    "scan-enabled" => false,
    "scan-interval" => 5000
}}}
}
```

The standalone/deployments directory in the JBoss Application Server 7 distribution is the location end users can place their deployment content (e.g. war, ear, jar, sar files) to have it automically deployed into the server runtime.